# Stars are living creatures?

Tags: rambam, science, astronomy

the Rambam in yesodei torah says that stars are creatures with intellect. how do we reconcile this with modern science which says that they are merely inanimate balls of hydrogen and helium gas.

Comment: He also thought Neptune didn't exist...

Comment: Does saying something has intellect necessitate it is 'living'?

Comment: This question would be stronger if you'd [edit] in why you believe that it's necessary to reconcile the Rambam's cosmology with that of modern science.

Comment: Well, modern science also says humans are balls of oxygen and carbon and the like, yet Jews believe in a soul. Perhaps the _Rambam_ believed stars have some spiritual component analogous to a human's soul, and this is what he meant. As you haven't cited or quoted the _Rambam_, it's hard to tell. −1.

Comment: @msh he says "inanimate" which humans are not.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so you think the contradiction the asker is noting is between inanimate (=nonmoving) and having intellect? What does one have to do with the other? (I'm really asking the asker, not you. Asker, please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean to ask.)

Comment: It'd be great if you could add the quote to the question.

Comment: Where is the Rambam exactly?

Comment: It is important to remember that the Tosafos Yom Tov and Chassam Sofer recognzed the fallibility of Rishonim in matters of metzius.

Comment: Stars do have a metabolism.

Comment: There might be beings with intellect living on planets orbiting around the stars.

Comment: @mevaqesh can you point me to source on this one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Rambam himself addresses your question. He writes the following in Moreh Nevuchim regarding the science in the Gemara:

> Moreh Nevuchim (3:14):
>
> אל תדרוש ממני להתאים את כל ענייני האסטרונומיה שהם ציינו אל המצב כפי שהוא, כי המתמטיקה היתה לקויה באותם זמנים. והם לא דנו בזאת מבחינת שהם מוסרים אמרות אלה מפי הנביאים, אלא מבחינת שהם היו חכמי אותן תקופות במקצועות אלה או שמעו אותן מפי חכמי אותן תקופות.
>
> Do not ask me to reconcile all matters of astronomy that they (the sages) stated
> about astronomy with the actual reality, for the science of those days
> was deficient, and they did not speak out of traditions from the
> prophets regarding these matters. Rather because they were the wise of that period in these matters or because they heard them from the wise of that period.

As such, the Rambam would tell you not to try to reconcile his approaches with our conventional scientific understanding. Like the sages, he was basing his teachings on the knowledge of the philospophers and mathematicians of his own time.

Comment: Yehuda that is correct.

Comment: That doesn’t address the first cause, especially if the first cause is G-d describing His own creation as He often is quoted doing in the Tanakh. Rambam was basing his view on a divine creator or a proto-evolutionary happen stance? If it is the former then he was obliged to conform to divine revelation, if it were merely human speculation what good was it without confirmatory proof?

Answer (score 3):

When they landed a man on the moon, one great rabbi (R' Yaakov Kamenetsky, I think?) observed: "well Rambam was quoting Aristotelian philosophy and thought the moon had an intellect; Ramban was a kabbalist and said it's a ball of mineral. Looks like Kabbala just beat Aristotelian philosophy."

Comment: You don't need Kabbalah to beat Aristotelian philosophy.

Comment: I heard that that was the only time that R' Yaakov Kamenetsky watched TV, and it was for the purpose of seeing with his own eyes which side of that dispute was correct.

Comment: @IsaacMoses and Shalom, One of my Rabbeim quoted a Rav who said of the lunar landing, "Don't believe everything you see on TV."

Comment: @shalom not exactly how Rav Yaakov wrote it,but it can be found in his sfer Emes Lyaakov page 15 in Bereishis.

Comment: who says astrology is from aristotle? (could well be he got it from us) there's quite a lot of stuff in the torah itself on it which was well before aristotle

Comment: Source please. For story and Ramban understanding the moon to be a ball of mineral.

Comment: And who was he compared to the Rambam? this beats out "every point" of philosophy? And yes like @Yehuda said, where is the source???

Comment: @ray Where does the Torah talk about astrology? Who even mentioned astrology?

Comment: 1. The Torah does not accept the view that astrology can affect our lives. 2. The Rambam, and hence Aristotle, did not think physical beings resided on the moon. He was saying there was something intelligent about the creation (ie G-d).

Answer (score 0):

I think that both Aristotle and Maimonides relied on the science of their day which was wrong in many ways. Yet, the Rambam, unlike his predecessors, did not believe in the efficacy of astrology. In Yesodei Torah, I do not think the Rambam literally believe that beings exist in these inanimate balls of hydrogen and helium gas.

I recognize that he only knew the science of his time and some of his ideas which were based on that science are erroneous. An example is his view that upon death the person's knowledge (intellect) joins the sphere of intellect that circles the earth. Today we know this is the soul and not the flow of the active intellect. His and Aristotle's view of women was also erroneous and based on false science.[1]

[1] By science, he said a woman had fewer teeth. But he was not a misogynist.