# Why are observant Jews so reluctant to admit that Chazal could ever make mistakes?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chazal, infallibility

I have great respect for many of our sages of blessed memory, but there seems to be a tendency among Jews to refuse to admit the possibility that they could have ever made mistakes.  I have been grappling with this question as I was trying unsuccessfully to write an answer to a [this recent question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53255/3483).  It is extremely hard to speak of the fallibility of our sages in a socially acceptable way.

One way to see this is to look at some of the reasoning on why we no longer follow Talmudic medicine. You often find something along the lines of the reasons given by the Maharil, that the descriptions are unclear, that we cannot understand what they mean, that if we tried it and did it wrong one might come to belittle the sages.

I almost never see an orthodox rabbi say: they were men who worked with the knowledge that was available at the time. They tried to apply Jewish principles to the world as they understood it, but they may have been mistaken in specific facts about the world.

The notion that any human could be infallible bothers me. I would gladly agree that Chazal were righteous, intelligent people with much integrity. I would also agree that is not good for people like us who have lesser moral qualities to criticize those who are greater than us, but does this mean that it is wrong to make respectful observations that such-and-such person was wrong about one particular issue that we can now understand in a completely different way? So they didn't know anything about germ theory or which creatures were real and which were mythical. Why is that so bad to say? Why do we tie ourselves in knots to avoid saying that they could be wrong occasionally?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38465/5323

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/an-improved-jewish-calendar-after-this-one-expires#comment55616_23060 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38021/759

Comment: I'm not sure the premise is right. I don't think anybody really thinks chazal are infallible.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe the premise *is* wrong. I would not mind that if other people's experience differs from mine.

Comment: @Daniel No one would say that but they would never say they were wrong either. They would say "yes it's possible for them to be wrong it just never happened".

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22752/759

Comment: Simple answer (no source, so no answer): We assume anything they said regarding medicine was a Halacha LeMoshe MiSinai (which can't be wrong) because if it wasn't, why write it in a Halacha Sefer (like the Gemara)? Write it in a seperate "medical" book

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If you ask a Posek if you can have stitches on Shabbat, should he answer the question directly or write the theory in one responsum and the details of how stitches work in a seperate letter?? Applying ונשמרתם מאד לנפשותיכם using current science IS Torah.

Comment: @Mike read this: http://leimanlibrary.com/texts_of_publications/73.%20R.%20Israel%20Lipshutz%20and%20the%20Mouse%20That%20is%20Half%20Flesh%20and%20Half%20Earth.pdf

Comment: I honestly think it begins in elementary school or earlier when we are told of all these wondrous stories of essentially miracles that happened 80 years ago, and that Rashi had reach hakodesh. Instead we should be learning first and foremost that people are PEOPLE, NOT GODS. I love Rashi, the Ramban, The Sages... They've changed my life. But they were HUMAN. That is a fact. They were not omniscient. Even the Prophets only caught a relevant glimpse. No one was taught biology, physics, chemistry... gimme a break!

Comment: @Daniel I would maybe qualify your statement as follows: No traditional opinions consider chazal infallible as individuals (the Talmud mentions a plethora of personal and scholarly mistakes made by sages), and there are certainly retracted and rejected statements found widely in the writings of chazal. However, there are some opinions that attribute some form of inerrancy to undisputed statements in chazal (though even those opinions often involve some nuance).

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22752/759 is highly relevant, but maybe not a duplicate. OP seeks to understand a phenomenon where, allegedly, Orthodox Jews overwhelmingly view every facet of every statement of chazal as inerrant. On second thought, I'm not exactly sure of the exact parameters of this alleged phenomenon, since obviously there are internally rejected and disputed statements within the writings of chazal that everyone recognizes as such. So perhaps this should be closed as unclear. Also, I think answers probably would primarily be opinion-based.

Comment: Downvoting per http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19801312#19801312. This question probably should be closed. cc @Fred

Comment: Ok I'm leaving this close as Primarily Opinion Based, per Fred, msh and Isaac, as discussed in chat.

Answer (score 2):

The book Torah Chazal And Science by R. Dr. Moshe Meiselman goes through the topic at great length (e.g. p. 33-4). His main thesis is that the primary approach of Jewish authorities through the ages has been to treat all **undisputed** statements of Chazal as correct.  He asserts that they assumed that just like in the halachic arena in which Chazal were clearly fallible as evidenced by their many disputes and the proofs brought against them, their conclusion is assumed to be correct and binding, so too in other matters although we know that they were fallible, we assume that their conclusions reflect truth.
He cites several examples of this and manages to present almost every statement to the contrary in Geonim or Rishonim as being somehow limited to the matter at hand.
Besides asserting that this approach is the traditional one, he asserts that as such this constitutes our Mesorah from which we will only deviate with absolutely indisputable evidence.
see also [here](http://slifkinchallenge.blogspot.com/) where this opinion is discussed (albeit in a sometimes acerbic tone).